# export data from gams to excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, gams-math

I have a mathematical model and I want to run it 10 times automatically with different data sets which are generated randomly(when the first model stops, start another model automatically). for this purpose I have written the solve statement in a loop  . I want to see the result of these 10 models in different sheets of an excel file. how can I do it? is it possible to correct my code?

set k/sheet1*sheet10/;

loop(k,

data generation....

solve statement....

execute_unload 'RESULT.gdx'

execute 'gdxxrw.exe RESULT.gdx o=RESULT.xlsx var=x.l rng='k.t1:0'!a1'

);

I really appreciate your kind helps

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are pretty close already, you just need to use 'put_utility' instead of 'execute' to make use of the 'k.tl' syntax (note: it is .t**l**, not .t**1**):

```
*dummy put file
file fx; put fx;

set k/sheet1*sheet10/;

loop(k,

solve statement....

execute_unload 'RESULT.gdx'

put_utility 'exec' / 'gdxxrw.exe RESULT.gdx o=RESULT.xlsx var=x.l rng='k.tl:0'!a1';

);
```

I hope that helps!
Best regards,
Lutz